# asp.net custom validator not firing for textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I have both a required field validator and custom validator for validating a texbox. The required field validator fires perfectly. I'm not able to get the custom validator to fire properly?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPRI" runat="server" Width="295" /><br />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator display="Dynamic" CssClass="leftAlign" SetFocusOnError="true"  runat="server" controltovalidate="txtPRI" errormessage="Please enter your PRI" />

 <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="cusCustom" controltovalidate="txtPRI" onservervalidate="cusCustom_ServerValidate" Enabled="true" ValidateEmptyText="true" display="Dynamic" CssClass="leftAlign" SetFocusOnError="true"  errormessage="The text must be exactly 8 characters long!" />
```

code behind

```
protected void cusCustom_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("firing - test");
        Response.End();


        if (e.Value.Length == 8)
            e.IsValid = true;
        else
            e.IsValid = false;
    }
```

Comment: I always have problems with serverside validators, I always end up going with client side :(

Comment: i'd also love to know the answer to this.

Comment: Is the method firing at all? Have you set it as the validator's OnServerValidate event? Can you show us the ASPX tag for the validator?

Comment: Nope not firing at all, the tags are there?

Comment: @jonezy: Be careful with client-side validators - they are easy to trick and submit malicious data. Always make sure you validate input on the server, one way or the other.

Comment: This is a tricky one. Just for testing purposes, put a `Page.Validate()` and/or a `cusCustom.Validate()` in the Page_Load or some other place where you know it will be hit. Then step through and watch it hit. I have a feeling the event isn't registered, although it does look like it is from your code. BTW, what version of ASP.NET is this?

Comment: @Eric: my comment was in response to @jonezy

Answer (score 53):

Check that you have the your `CustomValidator` property `ValidateEmptyText` set to `true` so that empty text will be validated.  Then you will not need the `RequiredFieldValidator` anymore.

**EDIT:** I took your code and copy and pasted it into an empty project and it works as expected.  There must be something you have not posted, or is posting incorrectly, that we are not aware of.  Is there anything else that affects the button that is triggering the validation or the validation controls themselves?

**EDIT:** Here is the exact code (it's in a content page):

aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPRI" runat="server" Width="295" /><br />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" display="Dynamic" CssClass="leftAlign" SetFocusOnError="true"  runat="server" controltovalidate="txtPRI" errormessage="Please enter your PRI" />  
    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="cusCustom" controltovalidate="txtPRI" onservervalidate="cusCustom_ServerValidate" Enabled="true" ValidateEmptyText="true" display="Dynamic" CssClass="leftAlign" SetFocusOnError="true"  errormessage="The text must be exactly 8 characters long!" /> 
</asp:Content>
```

.cs page (empty `Page_Load`):

```
protected void cusCustom_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{ 
    // put a break point here and it stops on it
    if (e.Value.Length == 8)
        e.IsValid = true;
    else
        e.IsValid = false;
}
```

Comment: really eh, so something in my code is interfering with the firing of the event.. i have a bunch of required field validators for other text boxes and that's all. They all fire properly??

Comment: @Eric Savard  You can do a simple test and just copy and paste the code you posted into an empty project.  It works fine. You need to isolate what is causing it so I would start by commenting out as much code as possible and get it to work and then add it back slowly to figure out which snippet is causing the problems.

Comment: Kesley, can you please send me the code.. because i did exactly what you did with a new web form and it still doesn't work

Comment: <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
  
  
<div class="floatLeft width35"><span class="red">*</span><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="PRI (8 characters):" /></div><div class="rightarm"><asp:TextBox ID="txtPRI" runat="server" Width="295" /><br /> <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="cusCustom" controltovalidate="txtPRI" onservervalidate="cusCustom_ServerValidate" Enabled="true" ValidateEmptyText="true" display="Dynamic" CssClass="leftAlign" SetFocusOnError="true"  errormessage="The text must be exactly 8 characters long!" /></div>
    </div>
    </form>

Comment: @EricSavard - Maybe I am commenting too late. But you need FieldRequired="True" to be set up sometimes it acts weird.

Comment: wow just wow... thanks man you saved the day... damn you Microsoft and your validators...

Answer (score 19):

Ok... really old question with no accepted answer yet, and I just ran into the same issue.

So I'm going to throw this out there for anyone else who might have this problem and needs an answer...

If your're doing regular validations, along with custom server validations, the custom server validation will only fire if all other validations come back clean, at least, that's the way it's worked for me.

Comment: Old post, but thank you for this reply anyways. This answered my questions :)

Answer (score 9):

Remember to set this property on the CustomValidator...

```
ValidateEmptyText="True"
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the suggestions above, I've found that with newer versions of the .Net framework you must explicitly fire the validate() method at the server to get the custom validator routine

```
    // validate page before allowing import to go through
    Page.Validate();
    if (!Page.IsValid)
        return;
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too. Yes all other validators have to pass **before** the `CustomValidator` fires.

However, if that does not work for you, then you may need to force a validate of **your specific validation group** using the `Page.Validate()`.

This is how I did it, and I still managed to keep my `RequiredFieldValidator` and no need for `ValidateEmptyText="true"`.

Add a trap in the textbox to force a validate.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLeft" runat="server" Width="110px" TextMode="SingleLine" style="text-align:center" OnTextChanged="TextBoxChanged_DateTimeTest" AutoPostBack="True" ValidationGroup="vg2"></asp:TextBox>
```

Note that I am using a specific `ValidationGroup` "vg2", as I have other areas that I don't want to validate.

Also, I want to validate date **& time**!

You need two more things. The `TextBoxChanged_DateTimeTest` method ...

```
protected void TextBoxChanged_DateTimeTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate("vg2");
        if (!Page.IsValid)
        {
            TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)sender;
            IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-AU", true);

            //if page is not valid, then validate the date here and default it to today's date & time, 
            String[] formats = { "dd MM yyyy HH:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" };
            DateTime dt1;
            DateTime.TryParseExact(tb1.Text, formats, culture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dt1);
            if (dt1.ToShortDateString() != "1/01/0001")
                tb1.Text = dt1.ToShortDateString() + " " + dt1.ToShortTimeString();
            else
                tb1.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        }
    }
```

And you also need the server side validate for the `CustomValidator`. In my case the TextBox has to accept a date & time!

So here's the markup...

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLeft" ErrorMessage="Invalid date & time format (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm)" 
                                    SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vg2" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator_DateTime"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

And here's the code behind ...

```
protected void TextBoxChanged_DateTimeTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate("vg2");
    if (!Page.IsValid)
    {
        TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)sender;
        IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-AU", true);

        //if page is not valid, then validate the date here and default it to today's date & time, 
        String[] formats = { "dd MM yyyy HH:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" };
        DateTime dt1;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(tb1.Text, formats, culture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dt1);
        if (dt1.ToShortDateString() != "1/01/0001")
            tb1.Text = dt1.ToShortDateString() + " " + dt1.ToShortTimeString();
        else
            tb1.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling [`Response.End()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which effectively stops all execution of the page. Thus, the if/else block isn't being run at all. Comment that line out or skip over it while debugging and the validator will fire as expected.

I suggest you use a debugger instead of writing responses out in this fashion or be aware of the consequences of `Response.End()` if you choose to use it.

Comment: yeah, i hear you but i'm just trying to make sure that the handler gets hit which it isn't.

Comment: @Eric have you tried commenting those `Response` lines out and running it? It works fine for me when I do so.

Comment: @Eric: I would have thought this was the problem too. You said the method isn't firing; have you set a breakpoint before this line and stepped through to verify?

Comment: really eh, not working for me at all.. this means that something else is interfering with it

Comment: Justin, yes i did set a break point and it's for sure not firing

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, custom validator will not fire if your textbox is empty.

Comment: a `CustomValidator` can fire on empty text if the `ValidateEmptyText` property is set to `true` as I have stated in my answer.  This should remove his requirement for a `RequiredFieldValidator` as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple part in your code and each part has some validator, create validateGroup for each part