# CustomValidator firing but not not preventing postback in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

I am using a CustomValidator  in ASP.NET as follows.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="AnswerCV" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" 
     ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="test" 
     OnServerValidate="CustomValidation" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Enabled="True" 
     ErrorMessage="You must fill in the text box.">
</asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="test" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button runat="server" Id="Button" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="test" 
     OnClick="Button_Click" />
```

In the code behind I have

```
protected void CustomValidation(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
        MessageBox.Show("It is firing!!!");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.IsValid = true;
        }           
}
```

And the button click method is as follows

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MessageBox.Show("I should not have fired.");
}
```

The `CustomValidation` method fires but the `Button_Click` method fires after that and then the "You must fill in the text box." error message displays. How do I prevent the `Button_Click` method from firing, when the text box is empty the validation is failing and triggering the error message, but after the `Button_click` method has fired?

The stackoverflow page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119821/asp-net-custom-validator-not-firing-for-textbox") offered  other solutions which I have implemented but still the Button_Click method fires.

**Aside:** And the client side solutions I can not use as I am dynamically going to add code in the `Init()` method that enables and disables the `CustomValidator` via a `CheckedChanged` event in only certain Radio Buttons. **End Of Aside**

I have also tried the `CustomValidator` without the `OnServerValidate` method and I have tried returning a boolean of `false` from the `CustomValidation` method cause a syntax error.

Comment: try setting the input type='button' on your button

Comment: setting my asp:Button to type = 'button' but that did  not fix the problem. I need it to be an asp:Button too.

Comment: try setting the property `UseSubmitBehavior` to `false` like `buttonName.UseSubmitBehavior = false; ` or in your code maybe like `Id="Button" CausesValidation="True" UseSubmitBehavior="False"`?

Comment: I tried those suggestions but still not working. Thanks.

Comment: Purpose is only to validate if TextBox is empty ???

Comment: Yes I have just determined that a regular RequiredFieldValidator would work. If that is what you were going to suggest, put it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Sometimes it just requires a step back to look at things.

Answer (score 0):

Please add one if condition in Button_Click Event

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        Response.Write("<script> alert ('I should not have fired'); 
            </script>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (IsValid) 
    { 
      Response.Write(" alert ('I should not have fired'); "); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I will test on Monday