# custom validator to check the age entered in the text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a text box on my web page for date of birth. I don't want anyone to enter the age less than 16. if someone enters the age less than 16 than I want to show the error message saying "Less than 16 age is not allowed". I want to write this validation on server side rather than client side script. Below is the date of birth field.

```
<input onblur="selfservice.dateBlurCallback(event)" data-options="{&quot;mode&quot;:&quot;datebox&quot;,&quot;overrideDateFormat&quot;:&quot;%-m/%-d/%Y&quot;,&quot;lockInput&quot;:false,&quot;usePlaceholder&quot;:&quot;mm/dd/yyyy&quot;,&quot;useModal&quot;:false,&quot;overrideSetDateButtonLabel&quot;:&quot;Set Date&quot;,&quot;showInitialValue&quot;:false,&quot;beforeOpenCallback&quot;:&quot;parseDateCallback&quot;}" name="field_RecordingDateID_DOT_StartDate" id="txtDOB" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="text" data-role="datebox" value="" runat="server"  ></input>
```

Below is my customvalidator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator Display="None" ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" OnServerValidate="ageValidator" ControlToValidate="txtDOB" ErrorMessage=""  />
```

and below is my server side code:

```
protected void ageValidator(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Parse(txtDOB.Value.ToString());
            TimeSpan sp = DateTime.Now - dtStart;

            if (sp.Days < 16 * 365)
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
                CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "You have to be at least 16 to order the Certificate";
            }
            else
                args.IsValid = true;
        }
```

I am not seeing any error message if the date of birth is less than 16. Also, application continues once this method is executed.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I did format my code.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: I modified my question

Comment: Did you try and debug to see if the server-side code is even kicking?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119821/asp-net-custom-validator-not-firing-for-textbox

Comment: Yes, server side code is kicking.

Comment: So what happened? Are you getting a value in sp.Days?

Comment: yes, I am, but the error message is not displaying.

Comment: Ok I see what's happening. The logic is working and you're populating the property of the control, but you;re not displaying. I suggest you need to incorporate an error dialog box in codebehind or javascript to handle exceptions.

Comment: cant I do it with ErrorMessage in customValidator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a `ValidationSummary` control with your asp.net control logic. Even if you populate a property in the `CustomValidator` control, it makes no sense to just leave it at that point.

Without writing the code entirely out for you, learn about ValidationControls here:

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/20822/custom-validator-and-validation-summary

Here is another excellent example:

https://meeraacademy.com/validationsummary-control-in-asp-net/